# context.WithTimeout seems to not release the goroutines created internally

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I have a simple implementation that uses `context.WithTimeout`, more or less like:

```
ctx, cancelFn := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Duration(time.Minute*1))

go func() {
    // do something
    cancelFn()
}()

select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        // ...
        return
}
```

When I monitor the number of currently existing goroutines (using `runtime.NumGoroutines()`), it seems that whenever the `WithTimeout()` function gets called, it internally creates a goroutine to keep track of the time and eventually cancel the context (which makes sense, if you look at the internals (https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/context/context.go#L401 and https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/time/sleep.go#L170).

However, when the context is finished and the case statement is reached, the goroutine is not being released. It seems that it keeps running forever and the resources are not released properly.

If I change the implementation to use a simpler version of a timeout, **without** the `context.WithTimeout()`, more or less like:

```
select {
    case <-time.After(time.Minute*1):
        // ...
        return
}
```

Then the number of goroutines is the expected in the first place and nothing seems to leak.

What could be the problem? What am I missing?

Comment: Are you having the context timeout or is the goroutine finishing its work and calling the cancelFn() when you see this leak?

Comment: `WithCancel`, `WithTimeout`, and `WithDeadline` all say the same thing in [their docs](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#WithTimeout): "code should call cancel as soon as the operations running in this Context complete". If you're not calling cancel, you may wind up with a leak.

Comment: I am calling the cancelFn